# While transferring my database from one computer to another I lost indexes and primary keys and now when

Tags: sql, database, auto-increment

While transferring my database from one computer to another I lost indexes and primary keys.

I simply want to just go through the database and Edit and modify it to put the indexes on the primary key column. I do know which columns I need to modify.

What is the best way to do it? Realize that I have data in the primary key columns.

Changing the column to primary key is easy but to edit and auto increment  `IDENTITY(1,1)` is not working without creating a temporary column and making it an auto increment primary key and copying contents to it and then deleting the original ID column and then copying the contents to it.

Does anyone know a better way? Thank you.

Comment: How did you transfer the database?

Comment: Not sure how I did it.  It was a very frustrating experience.

What is the best way to copy the database from the backup?